# Administrative boundary of Colorado State Forest

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I am looking for a file that contains the boundary of the Colorado State Forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to do this is search for locality admin site. then search it for gis. that gave me this:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=rsacco&title=Colorado%20Parks%20and%20Wildlife%20-%20Administrative%20Boundary%20Data

Comment: Thanks! [This dataset](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b1b27dc4bde744e490e0d1a9f9512032) actually contains the boundary of the Colorado State Forest (PropNum 0) I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This link is to the BLM's geospatial data for Colorado. You may find some useful stuff here:

http://www.blm.gov/co/st/en/BLM_Programs/geographical_sciences/gis/GeospatialData.html